# React JS: How to pass emoji to Firebase real-time db - why is it showing as object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using replace() in a js file of React JS project.

This works okay until I try to replace string with an emoji. Here are my attempts of turning 'smile' into a smiley face...

1

```
    let name = this.state.name;
    let preSmile = this.state.message.toString();
    let text = preSmile.replace("smile", <span role="img" aria-label="smiley">&#128512;</span>);
```

2

```
    let name = this.state.name;
    let preSmile = this.state.message.toString();
    let text = preSmile.replace("smile", <span role="img" aria-label="smiley"></span>);
```

3

```
    let name = this.state.name;
    let preSmile = this.state.message.toString();
    let text = preSmile.replace("smile", <span role="img">&#128512;</span>);
```

When the data is displayed in the Firebase real-time db, it shows like this...

```
"Please, show me that beautiful [object Object] of yours"
```

And the message displayed in the browser is this...

```
Mary: Please, show me that beautiful [object Object] of yours
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: your js is invalid, the second argument in replace() needs to be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.replace()` takes two strings (or a regex and a string) as input. `<span role="img">&#128512;</span>` is an object, so trying to use it with `string.replace()` will result in `[object Object]`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I was over-complicating things... simply using "" as the second string works...